# adding to list in while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have a problem with loop for game I am writing.
most of game's code is in while loop, the part I am concerned looks more or less like that:

```
while True:
  lista=[]
  somenumber=randrange(5,20)
  lista.append(somenumber)

  break
```

not a real code but shows idea. I want the list to expand each time the loop runs, but instead the list holds only number from current loop. Any idea how I can do it? I would like the list to expand witch each run of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You must mive this

```
lista=[]
```

Outside of your loop, otherwise you init that variable each iteration. Also you need to delete

```
break
```

As it breaks after first iteration. From other hand you need
some logic  to stop the loop otherwise you will be spinning till out of memory

Answer (score 0):

Define the list outside of the loop,

Each time it initiates a new list so that your list gets emptied/a new list is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the list outside while loop. 
The list is reinitialized everytime therefore holds only the current iteration value.

Answer (score 0):

Your break statement breaks the loop the first iteration through and your list gets redefined to be empty each iteration. The list should be outside the loop and the loop should only be broken when a certain criteria is met, otherwise it's an infinite loop. This can be accomplished with an `if (criteria): break` or `while (criteria to be met, not yet met):`

```
lista=[]
while True:
  somenumber=randrange(5,20)
  lista.append(somenumber)
  if (some selection statement):
    break
```

Another way to write it, for example if you want 25 items in your list, would be:

```
lista=[]
while len(lista)<25:
  somenumber=randrange(5,20)
  lista.append(somenumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
condition = 0 #start
limit = 10 #finish
lista=[]
while condition < limit: #while not yet reached finish
  somenumber=randrange(5,20)
  lista.append(somenumber)
  condition += 1
```

Comment: This will result in a infinite loop is the only problem

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys. I think I know what to do. The game I am doing is an old game from C64, not sure if it was anywhere outside of Poland and in Poland it's title was "Namiestnik" - a text strategy where you were running Roman Colony